Confusion about "del dot" version of polar Laplacian
I understand that if $f(x,y)$ is a function defined in terms of Euclidean coordinates, then
$$
\nabla f(x,y) = \big( \vec{\mathbf{e}}_x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \vec{\mathbf{e}}_y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \big)\big[ f(x,y) \big]
$$
and that
$$
\Delta f(x,y) = \left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \right) \big[ f(x,y) \big]
$$
which agrees with the "del dot" vector identity,
\begin{align*}
\Delta f(x,y) &= \left( \big( \vec{\mathbf{e}}_x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \vec{\mathbf{e}}_y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \big) \cdot \big( \vec{\mathbf{e}}_x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \vec{\mathbf{e}}_y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \big) \right) \big[f(x,y)\big]\\
&= \big( \nabla \cdot \nabla \big) \big[ f(x,y) \big]\\
&= \nabla^2\big[ f(x,y) \big]
\end{align*}
since
\begin{align*}
\left( \vec{\mathbf{e}}_x \cdot \vec{\mathbf{e}}_x \right) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right)^2  &= 1 \cdot \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\\
\left( \vec{\mathbf{e}}_y \cdot \vec{\mathbf{e}}_y \right) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)^2  &= 1 \cdot \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\\
2\left( \vec{\mathbf{e}}_x \cdot \vec{\mathbf{e}}_y \right) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)  &= 0 \cdot \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}
\end{align*}
Moreover, I also understand the derivations that lead to the gradient operator in polar coordinates:
\begin{align}
\vec{\mathbf{e}}_x &= (\cos\theta)\, \vec{\mathbf{e}}_r - (\sin\theta)\, \vec{\mathbf{e}}_\theta\\
\vec{\mathbf{e}}_y &= (\sin\theta)\, \vec{\mathbf{e}}_r + (\cos\theta)\, \vec{\mathbf{e}}_\theta\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} &= (\cos\theta)\, \frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \left(\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\right)\, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} &= (\sin\theta)\, \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \left(\frac{\cos\theta}{r}\right)\, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
\end{align}
which implies that
$$
\nabla = \vec{\mathbf{e}}_r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r}\vec{\mathbf{e}}_\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
$$
I also understand that the repeated application of these differential operators gets us the classic version of the polar Laplacian, found everywhere in textbook and online:
\begin{align*}
\Delta &= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right] + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right] \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[ (\cos\theta)\, \frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \left(\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\right)\, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \right] + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[ (\sin\theta)\, \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \left(\frac{\cos\theta}{r}\right)\, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \right]\\
&= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}
\end{align*}
But that part that is confusing me is that if $\Delta = \nabla \cdot \nabla$, then shouldn't
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} = \left( \vec{\mathbf{e}}_r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r}\vec{\mathbf{e}}_\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \right) \cdot \left( \vec{\mathbf{e}}_r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r}\vec{\mathbf{e}}_\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \right)\text{?}
$$
But using the fact that $\vec{\mathbf{e}}_r \cdot \vec{\mathbf{e}}_r = \vec{\mathbf{e}}_\theta \cdot \vec{\mathbf{e}}_\theta = 1$ and $\vec{\mathbf{e}}_r \cdot \vec{\mathbf{e}}_\theta = 0$, the right hand side (by my calculations) comes out equal to
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}
$$
which is missing the $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ term. What exactly is going on here? What is wrong about my calculations?

The error is is that, unlike in cartesian coordinates, in polar coordinates the unit vectors are spatially dependent (in particular, dependent on $\theta$):
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}\vec{e}_\theta = -\vec e_r, \qquad \frac{d}{d\theta} \vec e_r = \vec e_\theta.
$$
So when you apply your gradient operator twice, the cross terms do not identically vanish, in particular
$$
\frac{1}{r}\vec e_\theta \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\vec e_r \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right) = \frac{1}{r}\vec e_\theta \cdot\left( \vec e_\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \vec e_r\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta\partial r}\right) = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}.
$$

Ah! Yes. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
